# Is there really no padding=same option for PyTorch's Conv2d?

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm currently working on building a convolutional neural network (CNN) that will work on financial time series data. The input shape is `(100, 40)` - 100 time stamps by 40 features.

The CNN that I'm using uses asymmetric kernel sizes (i.e. `1 x 2` and `4 x 1`) and also asymmetric strides (i.e. `1 x 2` for the `1 x 2` layers and `1 x 1` for the `4 x 1` layers).

In order to maintain the height dimension to stay `100`, I needed to pad the data. In my research, I noticed that people who use TensorFlow or Keras simply use `padding='same'`; but this option is [apparently unavailable in PyTorch](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/3867).

According to some answers in [What is the difference between 'SAME' and 'VALID' padding in tf.nn.max_pool of tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37674306), and also [this answer on the PyTorch discussion forum](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/is-asymmetric-padding-of-style-same-available-in-pytorch/4354/7), I can manually calculate how I need to pad my data, and use [`torch.nn.ZeroPad2d`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#zeropad2d) to solve the problem - since apparently normal [`torch.nn.Conv2d`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#conv2d) layers don't support asymmetric padding (I believe that the total padding I need is 3 in height and 0 in width).

I tried this code:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

conv = nn.Conv2d(1, 1, kernel_size=(4, 1))
pad = nn.ZeroPad2d((0, 0, 2, 1)) # Add 2 to top and 1 to bottom.

x = torch.randint(low=0, high=9, size=(100, 40))
x = x.unsqueeze(0).unsqueeze(0)

y = pad(x)

x.shape # (1, 1, 100, 40)
y.shape # (1, 1, 103, 40)

print(conv(x.float()).shape)
print(conv(y.float()).shape)

# Output
# x -> (1, 1, 97, 40)
# y -> (1, 1, 100, 40)
```

It does work, in the sense that the data shape remains the same. However, is there really no `padding='same'` option available? Also, how can we decide which side to pad?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55140554/convolutional-encoder-error-runtimeerror-input-and-target-shapes-do-not-matc/55143487#55143487  have a look at that, it will give you a clue.

Comment: Really speaking, that feature is possible in Tensorflow due to its static computation graph. In PyTorch, there is a dynamic computation graph, so it's probably difficult to implement (otherwise they would have already done that). Within `nn.Conv2D`, as you say, there is only symmetric padding, but different padding can be done along different dimensions.

Comment: I think @akshayk07 is right and the dynamic nature of pytorch makes it hard; Here is a good implementation of 'same' padding in pytorch (for 2d conv): https://github.com/rwightman/pytorch-image-models/blob/master/timm/models/layers/padding.py#L28

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same issue some time ago, so I implemented it myself using a `ZeroPad2d` layer as you are trying to do. Here is the right formula:

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import __add__

kernel_sizes = (4, 1)

# Internal parameters used to reproduce Tensorflow "Same" padding.
# For some reasons, padding dimensions are reversed wrt kernel sizes,
# first comes width then height in the 2D case.
conv_padding = reduce(__add__, 
    [(k // 2 + (k - 2 * (k // 2)) - 1, k // 2) for k in kernel_sizes[::-1]])

pad = nn.ZeroPad2d(conv_padding)
conv = nn.Conv2d(1, 1, kernel_size=kernel_sizes)

print(x.shape) # (1, 1, 103, 40)
print(conv(y.float()).shape) # (1, 1, 103, 40)
```

Also, as mentioned by @akshayk07 and @Separius, I can confirm that it is the dynamic nature of pytorch that makes it hard. [Here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/3867#issuecomment-507010696) is a post about this point from a Pytorch developper.

Answer (score 9):

It looks like there is now, in pytorch `1.9.1`, according to the [docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.9.0/_modules/torch/nn/modules/conv.html#Conv2d).

> `padding='valid'` is the same as no padding. `padding='same'` pads
> the input so the output has the shape as the input. However, this mode
> doesn't support any stride values other than 1.

Comment: what value does padding='same' use? 0? same as last pixel? miror?

Comment: @OfirShifman see also [in the docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv2d.html): `padding_mode (str, optional) – 'zeros', 'reflect', 'replicate' or 'circular'. Default: 'zeros'`. That means you can choose but by default it will pad with zeroes.

Answer (score 1):

`padding='same'` and `padding='valid'` is possible in **Pytorch 1.10.0+**. However, `'same'` and `'valid'` for **padding** is not possible for when `stride > 1`.